# mBeans Client deployed on weblogic gives a security exception?

Tags: security, exception, weblogic, jmx, mbeans

iam trying to follow the documentation of the mbeans for weblogic and create a web application 
to access an already created custom beans running in another application deployed in the server .
iam using this code

```
   InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    MBeanServer    server = (MBeanServer)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");
    String serverName = System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");



         ObjectName on =new ObjectName("com.myCompanyName:Name=MyCutomBean,Type=MyCutomBean");
         boolean boolresult=(Boolean)server.invoke(on, "myMethod",
         new Object[]{"a","b","c"}
         ,new String[]{"java.lang.String","java.lang.String","java.lang.String"}); //throw exception
          out.print(result);
         out.print(boolresult);
```

when i try to access our custom beans i got this exception :

> Access not allowed for subject: principals=[], on ResourceType: Name Action: execute, Target: myMethod

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finally find a solution
to avoid this exception u need to authenticate your Context using the following :

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
      props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");

      props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,   "<userName>");
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "<password>");
      Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);  MBeanServer    server = (MBeanServer)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");
```

Hope this will help someone